# Multiple object array not working in At.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, at.js

I'm using [At.js plugin](https://github.com/ichord/At.js). It's working fine for a single object ([demo](http://jsfiddle.net/59y6j8tk/))

```
var names1 = ["Jacob", "Isabella", "Ethan", "Emma", "Daniel", "Madison"];
var names = $.map(names1, function(value, i) {
  return {
    'id': i,
    'name': value,
    'email': value + '@yahoo.com'
  };
});
```

But when I try to add multiple objects it's not working ([demo](http://jsfiddle.net/59y6j8tk/1/)). I knew the code is the problem.
I want to display the description when a user selects the name of the person using `@` tag.

```
$(function() {
  $.fn.atwho.debug = true

  var names1 = [{
      "name": "Jacob",
      "description": "description one description one description one"
    },
    {
      "name": "Isabella",
      "description": "description two description two description two"
    }
  ];

  var names = $.map(names1, function(value, description, i) {
    return {
      'id': i,
      'name': value,
      'email': description
    };
  });

  var at_config = {
    at: "@",
    data: names,
    headerTpl: '<div class="atwho-header">Service List <small>↑&nbsp;↓&nbsp;</small></div>',
    insertTpl: '${email}',
    displayTpl: "<li>${name}</li>",
    limit: 200
  }
  $inputor = $('#inputor').atwho(at_config);
  $inputor.caret('pos', 47);
  $inputor.focus().atwho('run');
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The map function in Jquery does not take each element in a object as the function argument, you get the entire object (the element in the list) and you then need to extract the name, and the description. You were almost there.

```
$(function() {
  $.fn.atwho.debug = true

  var names1 = [{
      "name": "Jacob",
      "description": "description one description one description one"
    },
    {
      "name": "Isabella",
      "description": "description two description two description two"
    }
  ];

  var names = $.map(names1, function(value, index) { //Here I have only used value
    return {
      'id': index,
      'name': value.name, //Here I take value.name from the object
      'email': value.description //And value.description from the object
    };
  });

  var at_config = {
    at: "@",
    data: names,
    headerTpl: '<div class="atwho-header">Service List <small>↑&nbsp;↓&nbsp;</small></div>',
    insertTpl: '${email}',
    displayTpl: "<li>${name}</li>",
    limit: 200
  }
  $inputor = $('#inputor').atwho(at_config);
  $inputor.caret('pos', 47);
  $inputor.focus().atwho('run');
});
```